# Is it possible to iterate an array that is declared in the loop header

Tags: bash

Is it possible to iterate an array that is declared somehow like the following POC below? Or do you essentially need to create a variable beforehand and then use `[@]` to expand the array.

```bash
for ref in (1 2 3 4)
do
  echo $ref
done
```

Comment: Since you know the array literally, there is no point to use array notation. `for x in a b c` simply iterates over a b c. Only if the list is calculated and therefore stored in an array (say: `list`), you would write `for x in "${list[@]}"`.

Comment: BTW, please remove the `sh` tag, because your question is irrelevant to `sh` (sind _sh_ does not have arrays).

Comment: Have a look at  `hellp for` which might give you some clue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set the list of values for loop as is:

```
for i in 1 2 3; { echo $i; }
for i in a 'b c' d; { echo $i; }
```

If it's just numbers you can also use these `{0..10}` constructions:

```
for i in {0..10}; { echo $i; }
for i in {000..099}; { echo $i;}
```

or `seq` if you need to specify ranges dynamically:

```
start=1
end=10
for i in $(seq $start $end); { echo $i; }
```

And if we say about list of arguments for script/function than it could be omitted in loop totally(it's used by default):

```
fun(){
   for i do
       echo $i
   done
}

$ fun 1 2 3
1
2
3
```

But IMO arrays are more convenient and could be reused/changed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you simply don't have the parentheses it does work.

```bash
for id in 1 2 3 4
do
  echo $id
done
```